# how to do even spaces between grid lines in both x and y axis using amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, amcharts, amcharts4

how to do even spaces between grid lines in both x and y axis using amcharts ?

I need to do equal spaces between grid lines you can see the picture.
what i need to change

this is my graph settings:

i am using amcharts 3

```
{
    valueAxes: [
        {
            gridAlpha: 0,
            includeAllValues: false
        }
    ],
    graphs: [],
    listeners: [],
    chartCursor: {
        onePanelOnly: true,
        leaveCursor: true,
        valueLineAxis :false,
        valueLineEnabled: false,
        valueLineBalloonEnabled: false,
        cursorPosition: 'mouse'
    },
    chartScrollbar: {
        oppositeAxis: false,
        offset: 30,
        updateOnReleaseOnly: true,
        selectedBackgroundColor: "#c1e6ee"
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        gridThickness: 1,
        minPeriod: 'fff',
        parseDates: true,
        minorGridEnabled: true
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhl85.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it work to set the

```
"synchronizeGrid": true,
```

as a main property of the chart config.
(https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amserialchart/#synchronizeGrid_property)

Maybe you have to check with the minHorizontalGap as well?
(https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/axisbase/#minHorizontalGap_property)